# Chromecast window.location.reload(true) throws undefined

Tags: javascript, android, chromecast, google-cast

A few months ago while developing application for Chromecast and Android devices I have used

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

a lot. It was used to reload JavaScript and images in Receiver.

Recently I got back to develop app and now when I use this command, I get **undefined** in console. Nothing reloads, Sender still can communicate with Receiver. I launch this command again and then, debug is detached, Chromecast crashes and it needs to be reloaded...After it reloads, I launch Sender which launches Receiver and still cache is not cleared. So I use command again and it works. But only one time. Second time, the same situation.

Any ideas what is wrong?

My Chromecast uses 220620 firmware version.

---

EDIT

Further investigation. Problem appears when I don't do anything for some time, for instance 50 seconds. If I do it right away or in a few seconds, it's OK.

Comment: try `history.go(0)` or `window.location.href = window.location.href`

Comment: Didn't help. I have added more details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could be the timeout when debugging. Try to add the following in your js:

```
castReceiverManager.start({maxInactivity: 600});
```

And that will wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading this question again, and I should say that what I use the most is to just hit F5 on devtools. Also make sure you have the option "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" enable for better results.